# How to get all the team member names (from History) who have worked on some list of bugs

Tags: sql, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

How to get all the team member names (from History) who have worked on some list of bugs in VSTS (Visual Studio)
I have tried with **History** keyword but it gets me only one user results. I need all the list of people worked on a particular bug. ?? Any Help plz

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user info from each revision (History) using [REST API (Revisions - Get)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/vsts/wit/revisions/get).

Just try below PowserShell sample to get all the team members worked on a particular bug:

**Note:** *Just specify the correct parameters in below sample, you need to create a **temp** folder under disk **D** if use it directly.*

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://{instance}.visualstudio.com",
   [string]$workitemId = "74",
   [string]$user = "test@hotmail.com",
   [string]$token = "password",
   [string]$templist = "D:\temp\history.txt", # Loop all the records (revisions) with the users who ever changed the specific work item. 
   [string]$userlist = "D:\temp\userlist.txt" # You can get the final users who worked on the specific work item from this text file.

)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemId)/revisions?api-version=1.0"            
$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
$revisions = $response.value.fields | where({$_.'System.State' -eq 'Committed'}) # Change the sate which you want to get it's changed date here 

#Get the history (revisions) with the changed by user
$witrevisions = @()

foreach($revision in $revisions){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "ChangedBy" = $revision.'System.ChangedBy'
        } 

    $witrevisions += $customObject      
}


# Output the response to temp txt file.
$witrevisions | Select-Object `
                ChangedBy | Out-File -FilePath $templist -Width 200


# Remove the duplicated records.
$hash = @{}      # define a new empty hash table
 gc $templist |  %{if($hash.$_ -eq $null) { $_ }; $hash.$_ = 1} >  $userlist
```

[image]

Comment: @Shravan Kumar Is the script working for you? any update?